# Submit same form to another page after the AJAX says sucess

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which is validated through AJAX and the problem is that after the ajax gives response `1` it should submit the same form to the same page.
As I have used `$('#bigform').submit()` this does not allow me to submit the form to the PHP that resides on same page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bigform').submit(function(event) {
        var captcha_checks = $('#password_again').val();
        $(this).validate();
        if (!$(this).valid()) 
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://trigma.com/mobile-app-development/verify_captcha.php',
            data: { captcha_checks: captcha_checks },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    $('#bigform').submit();
                }
                if (data == 2) {
                    $('#captcha_error').text("Invalid Captcha! Please fill captcha carefully");
                }
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: try removing the event handler before submitting again... in the success funtion... `$('#bigform').off().submit();`

Comment: It seems a little redundant to submit the form once, then again if valid. Why not change your server side logic to validate first, then proceed automatically in a single call?

Comment: on again submitting form you captcha code will be give validation issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Boolean variable like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var first = true;
        $('#bigform').submit(function(event) {

        if(first){
            var captcha_checks = $('#password_again').val();
            $(this).validate();
            if (!$(this).valid()) 
                return false;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://trigma.com/mobile-app-development/verify_captcha.php',
                data: { captcha_checks: captcha_checks },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        first = false;
                        $('#bigform').submit();
                    }
                    if (data == 2) {
                        $('#captcha_error').text("Invalid Captcha! Please fill captcha carefully");
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            else
            {
             $('#bigform').submit();
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: I will try this and update you. It seems to be the answer i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd thing to do, but if you must use a separate function, like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  function onSubmit(theElement){
       var captcha_checks = $('#password_again').val();
        theElement.validate();
        if (!theElement.valid()) return false;
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'http://trigma.com/mobile-app-development/verify_captcha.php',
          data: {captcha_checks:captcha_checks},
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {
            if(data == 1){
                onSubmit(theElement);
            }
            if(data == 2){
                $('#captcha_error').text("Invalid Captcha! Please fill captcha carefully");
            }
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  $('#bigform').submit(function(event){
      onSubmit($(this));
  });   
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set `click` event handler for the <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> button instead?

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $(form).validate();
    if (!$(form).valid()) 
        return false;

    //...your AJAX call...
        if(data == 1){
            form.submit();
        }
    //...

});
```

Comment: i have tried but then these jquery valdiations dont work